# Update exisiting site to 3.5 release candidate

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, updates, upgrade

I have an existing site that I want to update to 3.5 now, because I want to see if my plugins and themes work in it.

I don't want to wait for the full release (when I'll be able to automatically update), and I don't mind that 3.5 is still in release candidate state.

I could just copy in all the files from 3.5, but I'm afraid that there might be some database changes too.

I don't want to set up a separate test site. This is a small site, and it won't be the end of the world if something goes wrong.

How can I update an existing site to a non-final version of Wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [**Beta Tester Plugin**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-beta-tester/).

Be sure to set it to use **bleeding edge nightlies**, so that you get the pre-releases. Also: once a new major version is final-released, be sure to change the Plugin's settings back.

Comment: I installed and activated the plugin, but I don't see any settings page for it. I also clicked "Check Again" in Dashboard > Updates, but got nothing.

Comment: Did you check the `readme.txt` file or the [installation instructions](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-beta-tester/installation/)? "*Navigate to Tools ... Beta Testing to configure the plugin.*"

Comment: Of course I have. Would've been pretty stupid of me not to. But like I said, *I don't see any settings page for it*. There's nothing under the Tools menu. [See here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MFjPa.png).

Comment: Really? It's there for me, at **`Dashboard -> Tools -> Beta Testing`**.

Comment: I'm running **Wordpress version 3.4.2**, and I see no **`Tools`** menu under **`Dashboard`**. I thought **`Tools`** meant the stand-alone **`Tools`** menu. Did you see [my screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MFjPa.png)?

Comment: I had missed that; sorry. Please forgive another basic question: can you verify that the WordPress Beta Tester Plugin is **active**?

Comment: Of course! [Here's a screenshot of my plugins page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/W0oXk.png), and [here's a screenshot of my dashboard](http://i.stack.imgur.com/52IyQ.png). I feel pretty stupid now.

Comment: Looks like you installed the [**Plugin Beta Tester** Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/plugin-beta-tester/), instead of the [**WordPress Beta Tester** Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-beta-tester/). (Easy mistake to make. :) )

Comment: I see now that I was using the wrong plugin. Pretty stupid of me. I installed the other plugin, and it's working. Thanks.